# HTML5 video controls dissappears when video start playing

Tags: android, html, video

I have html5 video player displaying a video on a mobile device. Immediately the video has started playing the controls dissappears and doesn't appear until the video has finished playing. This is my video code

```
<video height="350px" width="350px" ng-src="{{post.Video}}" controls="controls"></video>
```

Please how do I make the controls display on the video especially when it is playing?

Comment: Could it be anything to do with the Angular template? Have you tried with pure Javascript?

Answer (score -1):

It just needs a little love:

```
<video height="350px" width="350px" stay-with-me-please="true"></video>
```

Let us know how that works ;)

Comment: Is this property found in the documentation?

Comment: No way? LOL :) :) :)

Comment: So what technology did facebook use in their mobile devices?